# Transaction configuration for Spring Java configured context

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations, spring-aop

I've been struggling with this for a few hours now.

I'm trying to migrate my Spring XML configuration to a full Java based configuration.

I'm using `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` as a context implementation.

I'm having trouble finding an Java equivalent for this line, from my old XML configuration:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

As a result, Spring doesn't manage the transactions.

In my Java configuration I have initialized the relevant beans for transactions: the session factory, the transactional manager, etc, but without that line, no transaction proxy is used, so no transactions are actually in place.

So my question is how do I either translate that line to my Java context configuration or how to I go about solving the problem in another way.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can now use @EnableTransactionManagement.

See: http://blog.springsource.com/2011/06/10/spring-3-1-m2-configuration-enhancements/

Comment: how tospecify which transaction manager to use here? for eg DataSourceTransactionManager

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, it's not practical to entirely replace the XML config with `@Bean`-style config. Some things do make more sense configured in java, specifically your own bean definitions. But when it comes to infrastructural-type declarations like `<tx:annotation-driven>`, the XML syntax is a lot more concise.

You *can* reproduce the same effect in pure java, but it ends up being cumbersome and unintuitive, since things like `<tx:annotation-driven>` are typically interactions of complex low-level Spring infrastructure classes that you really don't want to touch.

My advice - mix and match, using each of Java and XML for their own strengths. This is quite easy to do. I prefer to keep the normal XML ApplicationContext classes, and then declare my `@Configuration` classes as beans in that XML context, alongside things like `<tx:annotation-driven>`.

Comment: No, i don't think so. The annotation style is considerably richer in modern Spring versions than it was in Spring 3.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's what I suspected. We are attempting to update our legacy code to Spring 4, and as part of that process I would like to eliminate as much of our XML configuration as possible (as long as it makes sense, of course, but I feel that in most places the annotation-based approach is a better choice).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/17/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-featurespecification-support. Spring 3.1's FeatureSpecification classes such as TxAnnotationDriven are designed to solve exactly the problem described above.

Comment: 404 response when navigating the link, mate